# Path of file in res directory

Tags: android

I'm trying to Init baseApi, I put the tessdata folder in `app\src\main\res`

```
    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/tessdata", "eng");
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
```

But this is'nt working - the path does'nt exists, what is the correct path?

Thank you!

Comment: there is no path, resources are not mapped to a real file system

Comment: access resources directly via `android.content.res.Resources` class API

Answer (score 0):

You can only make a folder which you want to access in the external storage or internal storage.App cannot uses resources folder of its own..